# algorithm2e-like vertical lines for loops in listings package

Tags: listings, algorithm2e

Is there any way to set vertical lines for loops in pseudo-algorithms written with `listings` package, in an algorithm2e style?

As an example, see here: http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/Algorithms.pdf

The reason for my question is that I am using a pseudo-code syntax without *end while*, *end if* and so on, in order to save space, but then it is sometimes difficult to follow the structure of nested loops, specially in the case of large algorithms.

Comment: I guess you have good reason for not using the algorithm2e package?

Comment: @Verron, yes, I find it easier to maintain (make changes and whatever) those algorithms written with `listings`. Moreover, using `algorithm2e` and other similar packages is like learning another *programming language*.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354350/lstlisting-and-indentation-lines