# lstlisting and indentation lines

Tags: listings, code

I am using `lstlisting` and I try to add vertical lines on identation, like you can do using the package `algorithm`, but I do not find a way to do it.

Is it actually possible? Because I did not find any post about that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. If you post a question, which is not a fundamental question like "what is better: bibtex or biber", then add a MWE. What is also very helpful, is a picture of the desired output.

Comment: Ok ! :)
I meant something like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Latex-algorithm2e-if-else.png/300px-Latex-algorithm2e-if-else.png
Their is a line between the "while" and the "end" and I wish I could do the same using lstlisting: drawing a vertical line when there is identations.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do this, but I haven't found any way of doing it automatically.

Here's an example listing from a paper I'm working on:
[image]

What I did to achieve this is define a custom command to add in the vertical ruler and then manually insert it in the code after every indentation. This is a lot of work, but it does achieve the desired result.

The code inside the listing is formatted like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    ?\indentrule?@Override
    ?\indentrule?public void run() {
    ?\indentrule?   ?\indentrule?System.out.println("Hello world!");
    ?\indentrule?}
}).start();
```

I defined the `indentrule` command with a simple `vrule` and 2pt of horizontal spacing after it, to move the ruler just a tiny distance away from the actual code. Here I also use a customcolor for the rulers so they don't cause too much noise in the listing. This results in the following command:

```
\newcommand{\indentrule}{\color{code_indent}\vrule\hspace{2pt}}
```

The color is defined using the `color` package as:

```
\definecolor{code_indent}{HTML}{CCCCCC}
```

When defining your listing, you need to make sure you have an escape character set up, which allows you to use latex commands in the listing. In this case i used the question mark character, but any valid escape character can be used to replace it. To set up the escape character, you should use the `escapechar` parameter of the `lstlisting` environment. Such as in this case: `escapechar=?`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to automatize @FHannes's answer is to use LuaLaTeX to preprocess the code to add the indent rules.  In the following, I preprocess the *whole file* because at the time the buffer processing is being done, trailing whitespaces have been removed, but we want to keep them for indentation.

The main task here is to replace double spaces with an indent rule.

In `indentrule.lua`:

```
function add_indentrule(filename)
   -- A table containing a "reader" function for reading a line.
   local ret = {}
   ret.file = io.open(filename)
   ret.reformat = false
   ret.reader =
      function(t)
         local line = t.file:read()
         if line == nil then return line end
         if (string.match (line, "begin{lstlisting}.*#i")) then
            ret.reformat = true
            return line:gsub ('#i', '')
         elseif (string.match (line, "end{lstlisting}")) then
            ret.reformat = false
            return line
         else
            if (ret.reformat) then
               return line:gsub('  ', '$\\indentrule$  ')
            else
               return line
            end
         end
      end
   return ret
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('open_read_file', add_indentrule, 'add_indentrule')
```

Assuming your main file is `main.tex`, we now have to compile a `master.tex` that contains:

```
\directlua{dofile('indentrule.lua')}
\input{main.tex}
```

Now if `main.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\newcommand{\indentrule}{\color{gray}\rlap{\smash{\hspace{6pt}\rule[-.35em]{1pt}{1.45em}}}}

\begin{document}
\lstset{mathescape=true}
\begin{lstlisting}#i
void f() { 
  if (i == 0) {
    lorem;
    while (true) {
      check;
    }
  }
  return test;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: output]