# How to display vertical lines at indents in lstlisting?

Tags: formatting, pseudocode, lstlisting

I want to display vertical lines in indentations. I already found this thread: [Lstlisting and indentation lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354350/lstlisting-and-indentation-lines), but it isn't what I want.

This is how my attempt looks like:

[image: Displayed in PDF]

This is how I want it to look like (ignore all the colors, only the vertical line under the "if" and "for" with the line to the right in the end):

[image: Iwantittobelikethis1]
[image: Iwantittobelikethis2]

Here is my lstset initialization:

```
\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=2.9mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  otherkeywords={then,to},
  morekeywords={then,to},
  escapechar=?,
  tabsize=4
}
```

Here is my attempt (from the screenshot above):

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
SelectionSort (int[] A)
    for i = 1 to A.length-1 do
    $\mid$  small = i
    $\mid$  for j = i+1 to A.length do
    $\mid$  $\mid$  if A[j] < A[small] then
    $\mid$  $\lfloor$   $\lfloor$   small = j
    $\lfloor$   swap(A, i, small)
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that I had not shared the solution to this question since 2019.

As it turned out, the example I shared was not made using "only" LaTeX, but rather using [Ipe](https://ipe.otfried.org/) where custom lines were placed such that it looked like they were generated within LaTeX.

However, if there are good solutions using "only" LaTeX and packages, be sure to share them here.