# Adding Vertical Lines for Indents with lstlisting (or other package)

Tags: pdftex, listings, code, python, syntax-highlighting

I have some code that is formatted with the lstlistings package in LaTeX, which looks like:
[image]

However, when putting in longer code it can be difficult (especially on page breaks) to know how far indented the code is.

In Pycharm (an IDE for Python) they solve the problem by showing vertical lines to show the indent level:
[image]

Do you know whether lstlistings package can add the vertical lines that one is familiar with from Pycharm (as shown above)?

If lstlistings does not have this feature, are we aware of any package for latex / xelatex / lualatex with syntax highlighting for Python with this feature?

---

If vertical lines is not a possibility, then I know of the functionality in lstlistings with showtabs=True; the problem with it is that it is (in my opinion) not looking with the way that it uses underscores to show tabs, eg.:
[image]

Would it probably to reconfigure lstlistings on my own to remove the underscores and replace the small bumps above (that counts the number of of tabs) with small dots for example?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: similar: [lstlisting and indentation lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354350)

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you, I wasn't aware of that post!